# Correct quad topology around cut hole

Tags: modeling, topology

I found some tutorial, but it explains not too much.
I don't know how to tackle remaining part of the model.

#### I got subdivided cube with subsurface modifier applied.

Did cut out some shape for training purpose. I will extrude it later with some depth.

[image: Cube]

#### Fixed topology around hole

so it has proper edge loop.

[image: Edge Loop]

#### But what should I do about outer edge loops coming from other sides?

Should I make some tris/ diamonds to stop them from going onto shape?

Or maybe its actually okey and I should clean rest quads so all loops can enter.

I think "outer loops" should not go there and increase detail. This would also increase vertex count on this hole as I will extrude this hole as example (if I had different shape it could increase vertex cound even more).

[image: Outer edge loops]